# how to add vertical scrollbar in gridview in yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2

I have a database table with 12 columns and whole data successfully displayed them in the yii2 gridview but the problem is the 12 columns will not fit in the window. I want to add a vertical scroll bar in grid view. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to put a div around it and then set the overflow using CSS. You will need to set the height.

```
overflow-y: scroll;
Height:?
```

Comment: please let me know if my answer helped you, if it helped please vote ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

you can use kartik . this package will auto give horizontal scroll. http://demos.krajee.com/grid#gridview